# jQuery Deferred not being rejected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I have the sample code below which uses jQuery deferred.  What I can't seem to understand is although the brushTeeth function returns a promise that is rejected, why is collectionResults which is another deferred always being resolved.

Some jQuery deferred reading says if the functions passed in $.when are not promises, they will be resolved right away, but brushTeeth actually returns a promise.

Clues what I am doing wrong here?

```
ShowerModule = ( function($) {
                    function init(){
                        var result = $.Deferred();
                        var collectionResults = $.when(brushTeeth);
                        collectionResults.done(function(){
                            console.log("done");
                        })

                        collectionResults.fail(function(){
                            console.log("reject");
                        })

                    }

                    function brushTeeth() {
                        var result = $.Deferred();
                        result.reject('["bah"]');
                        return result.promise();

                    }

                    return {
                        init : init
                    }

                }(jQuery));
            ShowerModule.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

```
var collectionResults = $.when(brushTeeth);
```

Line above should have been

```
var collectionResults = $.when(brushTeeth());
```

Comment: Yes, and unless this is a simplification of something more extensive, then `.when()` is unnecessary. `brushTeeth().done(function(){...}).fail(function(){...});` will give the same effect. Use `.when()` for responding to the combined resolution of multiple promises.

Comment: yes, it's a simplistic example.  I use .when() in the case of 2 or more promises that need to be resolved:)

Answer (score 0):

you have created two deffered object with the samename `result`

so i guess $.when is taking the one above it as promise.. is which is not rejected..
try this

```
 function init(){
                   // var result = $.Deferred(); remove this
                    var collectionResults = $.when(brushTeeth()); //accept function and not the function's reference
                    collectionResults.done(function(){
                        console.log("done");
                    })

                    collectionResults.fail(function(){
                        console.log("reject");
                    })

                }
```

Comment: But each of those results variable will be local to the function it is contained in.  Anyways, I edited the code here, but still same results http://jsbin.com/oyemez/1/edit

Comment: ok..your code is giving you done.. since your are passing the reference of the function and not function itself...here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/oyemez/6/edit  ....try this `$.when(brushTeeth());`